# How Can I Proof $1+2\cos(\theta)+2\cos(2\theta)+2\cos(3\theta)+.. $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Proof

$1+2\cos(\theta)+2\cos(2\theta)+2\cos(3\theta)+...+2\cos((n-1)\theta)=\frac{2\sin((n-\frac{1}{2})\theta)}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta)} $

Comment: Why don't you multiply the sum of cosines on the left by $\sin(\theta/2)$ and use the formula
$$2\cos\alpha\sin\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)-\sin(\alpha-\beta).$$
First do this for small values of $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then for full proof either induct on $n$ or see if there's a trick.

Comment: In other words, you should show your own thoughts.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is a duplicate but I didn't find the link yet.

Answer (score 3):

One of such proofs is: $1+e^{i\theta} + e^{2i\theta}+\cdots + e^{(n-1)i\theta} = \dfrac{e^{ni\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}$. Then take the real part of both and equate them.

Comment: Did you search for duplicates first?